# enable access via ssh-key without using ~/ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: sshd

i want to enable access to a  home dirs via ssh/scp with an key.
Normally i would place the pub key into ~/ssh/authorized keys
But i want

- disable the ability to add or remove ssh-keys (turn off ~/ssh/authorized_keys)
- The user should not be able to rm -f pub_key, modify pub_key wherever it sits in the system
- make the directory where the pub keys for different accounts are stored not readable for "normal" user, e.g. like /etc/sudoers.d/ is only readable by root1

Is that possible? How would i do that?

Comment: See troubleshooting section of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: The trouble shooting section  allows the user to modify the authorized_keys, because it sets the pub_key to user permissions.

Comment: AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys

Comment: See 2 sentences befor this statement,  "This directory should have 755 permissions and be owned by the user."    again the user can do what he wants with the file (he owns it)

Comment: True --if they know where it is

Comment: security through obscurity is not a solution  A "find / -exec grep "mykey" {} does the trick.  Too easy for anybody with unix experience

Comment: In my previous company we had sort of solution you are planning. It was implemented by having SSH proxy, where every user was connecting with its key using common username (e.g. sshproxy@host). SSH proxy was recognising the user and then it was rerouting the connection to actual server ( if the user was permitted). Maybe this one could be used here https://github.com/tg123/sshpiper

Comment: But I'd guess they recommend 755 perms so that `ssh-copy-id` works. I see no immediate reason why it needs to be writeable by the user.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that you want to achieve:

- **Disallow the authentication using `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`**

  As proposed set `AuthorizedKeysFile` to some different place. If there is the discussed requirement, it will not be evaluated (otherwise there is nothing more to solve).
- **Set `AuthorizedKeysCommand`**

  The command will return you the authorized keys from your the location of your own choice.

For example:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/sbin/get_user_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser dedicated_user
```

And your script `/usr/sbin/get_user_keys` might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

This makes basically the keys read-only and solves your issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's one thing you can do without editing system configuration files to get most of what you want. You'd just use `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and all the rest like normal and make those immutable.

You can set the `~user/.ssh` directory immutable, which prevents moving it or deleting it, which is important if you don't want them to create a new `.ssh` with their own contents. It also prevents adding, moving, or deleting files within it.

You can set various files (like `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `~user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) immutable, which prevents moving them or deleting them. It also prevents editing them.

Note that immutable directories and files are protected in this way ***even against their owners***. They're even protected in this way against the `root` user until `root` removes the immutability.

Make sure to set the permissions for the directories and files properly for privacy before setting them immutable, since immutability blocks even that.

You set something immutable like this:

```
sudo chattr +i [directory path|file path]
```

A particularly convenient command protects `.ssh` and all files within it (recursively if you have subdirectories) in one go:

```
sudo chattr -R +i ~user/.ssh
```

To turn off immutability to change something (make sure to turn it back on when you're done):

```
sudo chattr -i [directory path|file path]
```

Note that a quick way to be able to edit whatever you want is:

```
sudo chattr -R -i ~user/.ssh
```